# WinForms pass through clicks to controls below another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a following form in WinForms as a prototype for a game:

[image]

`GestureControl` is a transparent Control that handles its `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events to allow for swiping gestures. Then there are `SquareControls` (game pieces) that should be clickable as well.

I'm not sure how to arrange these controls so both

- `SquareControl` will receive Click event
- `GestureControl` will receive MouseDown and MouseUp events

I know I could add a `Click` Gesture to my GestureControl (when the distance between mouse down and mouse up is not far away), pass it to parent and invoke the same event handler **as if** the corresponding SquareControl was clicked, but this seems hackish.

Comment: Add timer to mouse down event, stop it at mouse up.
If the time is below what you expect, execute Click Event, else do the other action

Comment: just want to give you a small advice. why don't you go with WPF it's give you great UI.

Comment: because the game will be made in Unity anyway, this is just for prototyping